# Variables in my authentication code don't seem to be adding

Tags: python

Its coursework. I know this is possibly the worst way I could do this, but I need to do it this way. The code works by seeing if the user inputs for usernames and passwords match the predefined details (saveduser1), etc. then it adds 1 to the variable 'authnumber'. If all details are correct, then it would leave authnumber equal to 4. For some reason, when I return authnumber at the end, it doesn't seem to be adding anything.

```py
import random
import time
saveduser1 = ("user1")
savedpass1 = ("pass1")
saveduser2 = ("user2")
savedpass2 = ("pass2")
authnumber = 0

print ("Player one, please input your username.")
player1user = str(input())
print ("player one, please input your password.")
player1pass = str(input())
print ("Player two, please input your username.")
player2user = str(input())
print ("player one, please input your password.")
player2pass = str(input())

if player1user == saveduser1:
    authnumber + (1)


else:
    authnumber = 0



if player1pass == savedpass1:
    authnumber + (1)
else:
    authnumber + (10)

if player2user == saveduser2:
    authnumber + (1)
else:
    authnumber + (0)

if player2pass == savedpass2:
    authnumber + (1)
else:
    authnumber + (0)

if authnumber >= (4):
    print ("opened")


else:

    print (authnumber)
```

Comment: you dont save authnumber + (1) anywhere, you need to do something like authnumber = authnumber + (1) (authnumber += (1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reassign `authnumber` to itself to change its value. Also remove redundant parentheses in your code.

```
import random
import time
saveduser1 = "user1"
savedpass1 = "pass1"
saveduser2 = "user2"
savedpass2 = "pass2"
authnumber = 0

print ("Player one, please input your username.")
player1user = str(input())
print ("player one, please input your password.")
player1pass = str(input())
print ("Player two, please input your username.")
player2user = str(input())
print ("player one, please input your password.")
player2pass = str(input())

if player1user == saveduser1:
    authnumber += 1


else:
    authnumber = 0



if player1pass == savedpass1:
    authnumber += 1
else:
    authnumber += 10

if player2user == saveduser2:
    authnumber +=1
else:
    pass

if player2pass == savedpass2:
    authnumber += 1
else:
    pass

if authnumber >= (4):
    print ("opened")


else:

    print (authnumber)
```

Comment: didn't have to change a thing, works perfectly my guy. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We need to do:

```
authnumber += x    # Or: authnumber = authnumber + x
```

Instead of:

```
authnumber + x     # This just calculates "authnumber + x", but does not assign it to "authnumber".
```